# How to resize images on page on different screen size?

Tags: html, css

How to resize images on my presentation website depending on different screen resolutions? For example, on a resolution like 2560x1440 the width of the images is too big. I want it to go from 28% to 20% because that's how i think it will look better. But only for that screen resolution, in other screen resolutions like 1280x720 it's ok.

This is an image of what i'm saying, with the 28% width: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoHyw.jpg

And this is how i want to transform it, with 20% width on that specific screen resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj5fk.jpg

This is my trying in CSS, but not working:

```
@media (max-width: 2000px){ 
  .amenajari_interioare_css{
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML and CSS code:

HTML:

```
<section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>LOCUINȚE</h1>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta3.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta5.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="amenajari_interioare_css">
            <img src="../img/locuinta6.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.amenajari_interioare_css{
    min-width: 350px;
    width: 28%;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.amenajari_interioare_css img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple errors in your CSS - mainly the media query. It should be `min-width`, because you want the change to happen for screen sizes **above** 2000px.

```
@media (min-width: 2000px){

.amenajari_interioare_css {
    width: 20%;
    }
}
```

The other thing you should probably do is:

```
.amenajari_interioare_css img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Set the `height` to `auto` or in the event you don't have a perfectly square image, otherwise that image will get stretched.

Comment: Thank you! I have another issues with images. If you want to help me, u can contact me here, i guess..

Comment: @TonyMoldovan sure thing...what's your issue

Comment: Um.. i got it, bro. Thank you anyway! It was something with adding "!important" in some code and now it's what i want. Thanks again!